# Is it possible to use restriction containers in a database query in an eID-script?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In an eID-script I use the *QueryBuilder* to get some records from the database. The query also returns hidden and deleted records although I would expect the *DefaultRestrictionContainer* to exclude those records.
Is some kind of initialization neccessary to make restriction containers work? Is it possible at all to use restriction containers in eID-scripts?

Calling `$queryBuilder->getRestrictions()` shows the *DefaultRestrictionContainer* does exist.
Calling `$queryBuilder->getSQL()` shows the restrictions are not added to the query.

The query is as simple as this:

```php
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('my_table');
$statement = $queryBuilder
    ->select('a', 'b')
    ->from('my_table')
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('c', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(123, \PDO::PARAM_INT))
    )
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the default restrictions [need a fully loaded TCA](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/3c275ff1bf13a7bf0e35008c72027d86438ea42f/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/Restriction/DeletedRestriction.php#L39). In eID-Scripts no TCA is loaded so you'll need to do this manually, e.g. with `EidUtility::initTCA()`.

Notice that this method [is deprecated](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.0/Deprecation-81201-EidUtilityinitTCA.html) and will be removed with TYPO3v10 where TCA is loaded at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Calling `EidUtility::initTCA()` solved the problem.